# Using ng-repeat with directives to create a table that adapts to data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I have a table that uses ng-repeat to iterate through an array of objects.  All the objects in the array have the same keys.  I want to make it so that an arbitrary set of keys could used, so long as the keys were consistent within that array.  It seems I need a directive that will generate and append

```
<td>{{key}}</td>
```

as needed, perhaps by iterating through Object.keys(array[0]).

For example, the table could accept either of the follow structures:

```
{ date: 1425535595000, name: "Name", desc: "some description" }
{ a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d" }
```

The appropriate bindings would be generated accordingly:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <td>{{date}}</td><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <td>{{a}}</td><td>{{b}}</td><td>{{c}}</td><td>{{d}}</td>
</tr>
```

I am a little weak on directives, and I am not 100% about the best way to go about it.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two ngRepeat directives, one for rows and one for table cells:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/AG1sh3UHImJgiONWbVA2?p=preview

Comment: well that was absurdly easy...
Is there an easy way to ignore certain keys using this solution?  Like if I never wanted to display a key named date.
I assumed I would be needing to write a function of some kind to accomplish this and was going to filter out certain keys there.

Comment: You can use a helper function or for simple cases ngIf will work too: http://plnkr.co/edit/w5imnQAua26HW3PkKelW?p=preview

Comment: Thank you.  I love the simplicity of the solutions.